# Include msgpack in cocos2d-x 3

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0, msgpack

I want to use msgpack with cocos2d-x 3.
I add include_directories(msgpack/include) in cocos2d/cocos/CMakeLists.txt. but not found msgpack.hpp.
How I can include and compile msgpack with cocos2d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have a look at https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c. Just put content of `msgpack-c/include` in yourproject/Classes and add line `#include <msgpack.hpp>` to you cpp file.
2. Don't add stuff in `cocos2d/cocos/CMakeLists.txt` because it is build file for cocos library. Add msgpack in `yourproject/CMakeLists.txt`
3. cmake in cocos2dx actually only for linux.